# Trying to initialise an instance variable to an instance of a shape with a diameter and a colour

Tags: java, bluej

I have written a class StickFigure that is a simplified representation of the familiar 'stick person'. In order to show stick figures in the Graphical Display, I have reduced it to the bare essentials and built it out of a Circle, a Triangle and a Rectangle.

The StickFigure has an xPos and a yPos which are also the only 2 instance variables.

I have so far made declarations for three further instance variables head, body and leg that will reference instances of Circle, Triangle and Rectangle. I think I have done it correctly

```
Circle aHead = new Circle();
Triangle aBody = new Triangle();
Rectangle aLeg = new Rectangle();
```

I am now trying to create constructor for StickFigure so that it initialises Head to an instance of Circle with diameter 30 and colour Colour.PINK. I am not sure how to do this! below is what I have done so far

```
public StickFigure()
{
    super();      
    this.setXPos(25);
    this.setYPos(220); 
}
```

The whole code so far:

```
`public class StickFigure { /*Instance variables*/
```

`private int xPos;//The horizontal position of a StickFigure`
 `private int yPos;//The vertical position of a StickFigure`

//my declarations 
`Circle aHead = new Circle(); 
Triangle aBody = new Triangle(); 
Rectangle aLeg = new Rectangle();`

   /**
    * Constructor for objects of class StickFigure that 
    * provides a default stick figure near the bottom left corner of the graphical display.
    * 
    */

`public StickFigure()`
{
 `super();

      this.setXPos(25);`

```
this.setYPos(220;
```

{

Comment: Where have the `Circle` and `Triangle` classes come from? Which package?

Comment: I created the stick figure in shapes using those shapes and now im writing a programme and those are the classes. Blue J

Comment: I think your aim is to include the three shapes making up the stick figures as instance variables, as they are ultimately bound to your stick figure. Then you just initialize all three shapes in your constructor, using desired parameters. You might want to look at the difference between composition and aggregation in object-oriented programming.

Comment: I understand that. But how you can manipulate those shapes will depend on which `Circle` class you actually used. Java doesn't have a `Circle` class so if you didn't write it then it must have come from somewhere else. Googling "java bluej circle" comes up with nothing. If you tell us which package it belongs to, that should unambiguously identify what you are working with and allow us to help you.

Comment: Your stick figure is composed by a head, a body and legs, therefore it should contain instance variables of each part. In the Circle class, you might add a Colour enum variable, so you can set its colour accordingly (in this case, each part would have a different colour) or add it directly to the sticky figure if you want just one colour.

Comment: The Circle, Triangle and Rectangle that make up the StickFigure object will be created in the StickFigure constructor and will use the provided getter methods in the class to obtain references to these so the StickFigure can be displayed in the Shapes Window.

Comment: Stateless Dev. That is what I am stuck at. How I set the colour of just the circle class at the moment as well as the diameter

Comment: This is what @Michael was getting at.  We don't know what constructs these shapes are.  For example, `Circle` could have a `Color` field on it, and some `drawTo(Graphics g);` method, in which case the answer would be obvious.  It might also be that you have some custom `ShapeDrawer` class which handles working out how to draw the different things, etc.  Without seeing more code, people will have a hard time suggesting things (although I suppose this comment has 2 ideas if nothing else).

Comment: I have added what I have done so far above.

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible and very basic solution:

```
enum Colour {
    BLACK,
    WHITE
}

class BodyPart {
    Colour colour;

    public BodyPart() {}

    public BodyPart(Colour colour) {
        this.colour = colour;
    }
}

class Circle extends BodyPart {
    private int diameter;

    public Circle(Colour colour, int diameter) {
        super(colour);
        this.diameter = diameter;
    }

    //getter and setter
}

class Triangle extends BodyPart {
    //whatever you want here
}

class Rectangle extends BodyPart {
    //whatever you want here
}

class StickFigure {
    private Circle head;
    private Triangle body;
    private Rectangle leg; // it could be a list of legs :D

    public StickFigure(Circle head, Triangle body, Rectangle leg) {
        super();
        this.head = head;
        this.body = body;
        this.leg = leg;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StickFigure sf = new StickFigure(new Circle(Colour.BLACK, 10), new Triangle(), new Rectangle());

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Dev, I have added the full code. What I have done so far